# Linear Algebra- Matrix derivative

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have a question related to finding derivatives of matrices. What is the derivative of $$(A.X)*(X^n)*(X.B)$$ with respect to $x_{11}$ ?
. is the element wise product
* is matrix product
$x_{11}$ is the element in first row and first column of $X$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: These matrices... they are functions of what? How many independent variables are there? Does x11 mean $x_{11}$?

Comment: yes.. x11 mean x11.. X=[x11  x12 x13; x21 x22 x23; x31 x32 x33]

A and B can be constant matrices or function of any of these 9 variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this question has no interest and it is a homework. If $A,B$ do not depend on $x_{1,1}$, then the derivative is the following matrix:

$(E_{1,1}.A)*X^n*(X.B)+(A.X)*(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}X^k*E_{1,1}*X^{n-k-1})*(X.B)+(A.X)*X^n*(E_{1,1}.B)$

where $E_{1,1}$ is the matrix with $0$ entries except the $(1,1)$ entry that is $1$.